# fix duplicated levels in factors after use of read_dta, haven package

Tags: r

I am using survey data on farmers in Nigeria from the World Bank (LSMS-ISA), available on the web. The data is in .dta and I am importing using the haven package.

When I import the file, I am getting the error message that "duplicated levels in factors are deprecated". I understand the problem and I am able to fix it (see below) but my solution seems very inefficient. I would appreciate it if somebody could come up with a better solution as I will probably need to fix other data sets as well.

This is what I tried:

The data file: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/gkuw01vlr68j2sw/secta1_harvestw1.dta?dl=0

This gives the error

```
loc <-  read_dta(file.path(dataPath, "/secta1_harvestw1.dta")) %>%
transmute(state = as_factor(state), region_lsms = as_factor(lga))
```

My solution:

```
loc <-  read_dta(file.path(dataPath, "secta1_harvestw1.dta")) %>%
      transmute(state = as_factor(state), lga)

# Create label-number table
lga = attr(loc$lga, 'labels')
name_lga <- names(lga)
link <- data.frame(lga, name_lga)
count <- as.data.frame(table(name_lga))
# Six label names with multiple labels in lga
loc2 <- left_join(loc, link)
loc2$region_lsms <- factor(loc2$name_lga)
```

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your factor with repeated levels is called `fac`, then I think this should work:

```
fac <- factor(fac, levels = unique(fac))
```

At least, it worked for my toy example; you haven't provided a reproducible example so I couldn't test it with that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that does not work. My variable (lga in the example above) is not a factor but of class "labelled", which is created when you import a .dta Stata file using haven. I provided a link to the data file so I think you should be able to reproduce my problem (only need to adjust the location of the file).

Comment: Worked for me using your data.

Comment: Technically this works loc$lga <- factor(loc$lga, levels = unique(loc$lga)) but it turns the numbers into a factor and drops the labels  (lga are areas in Nigeria that are numbered and have a label attached). What I want is that the numbers and labels are combined in a factor, and the labels are shown. This is what my solution does and as_factor is supposed to do. I have modified the code above so that is also includes a second variable "state", which does not have duplicated labels and can be processed with as_factor for comparison.